# How to do multiple http request using akka HttpRequest?

Tags: akka-http

I am new in akka and I need to do a process that sends multiple API request, defined by a concrete TPS (Transactions per second).

I have read aboud Akka HttpRequest but I don't know how to launch multiple request in parallel.

Thank you everybody.